JHipster microservice with Java 21: High latency in production environment
I have a microservice application built using JHipster and Java 21, with the following setup:
Client-side microservice: Developed using Java 21 and Vue.js.
Server-side microservice: Built with Java 21, acts as a data server.
The issue arises when the client-side microservice calls the server-side microservice to fetch data.
In the test environment, the response time is fast (sub-second).
In the live environment, the same request takes more than 12 seconds to complete.
Here’s the key difference between the environments:
Test Environment: Java 21 and Oracle 19c.
Live Environment: Java 21 and Oracle 11g.
I suspect the issue might be related to the configuration of the live server or compatibility issues with Oracle 11g.
Things I have checked:
Both microservices are functioning correctly in isolation.
No unusual logs or errors in the application.
Database queries are optimized and execute quickly when tested directly in the database.
Questions:
Could Oracle 11g be causing this delay due to compatibility or performance issues with Java 21?
Are there specific configurations or optimizations required for JHipster or Spring Boot to handle such a setup in a live environment?
What additional steps should I take to debug and resolve this issue?
Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
